# MongoDB - $gt date returns day and month correctly but shows previous years

Tags: mongodb

I save date in the database 09/29/2017 format using

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
```

The issue is that when I run

```
return Appointments.find({date: { $gt : todayDate }});
```

where todayDate is 09/29/2017 it returns days and months correctly but includes previous years, so the result of above may be: 09/30/2017, 10/01/2017, 09/30/2016

How can I fix the year issue? Changing everything to save in the format like this 2017-09-29T20:17:05.856Z is not a preferable solution for me because I'll need to make lots of changes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

`return Appointments.find({date: {$gt: new Date(todayDate).getTime() }});`

and if it doesn't work try this as well:

`return Appointments.find({date: {$gte: new Date(todayDate).toISOString() }});`

Comment: `new Date(todayDate).getTime()` with `todayDate="09/29/2017"` returns `1506668400000` and `new Date(todayDate).toISOString()` returns `2017-09-29T07:00:00.000Z`. If I do `var options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: 'numeric' }; const date = new Date(todayDate).toLocaleDateString("en-US",options); and then {startDate: { $gt : date }}` it makes no difference and shows the same 2017 and 2016 result.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to 2017-09-30 format and it started working correctly.